# Comprobar si un string está en un array de strings, no me está funcionando Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, string, ecmascript-6

Estoy intentando saber si un archivo tiene un tipo de archivo dentro de un array de archivos, pero al hacer mi código este no me está funcionando de ninguna manera, no se que puedo estar haciendo mal.

```js
console.log("El archivo es", this.archivoAbierto);

    let arrayTipoArchivosTextoSoportados: string [] = ['sql', 'text', 'doc'];

    arrayTipoArchivosTextoSoportados.forEach(tipo => {
      console.log(tipo, this.archivoAbierto.tipoArchivo);

      console.log(tipo.includes(this.archivoAbierto.tipoArchivo));
      
    })
```

Estos logs lo que me indican es lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se porque no se indica como true el contenido, ya que si que contiene el tipo de archivo en el array de tipos de archivos

Comment: ¿Queres saber si el mime o si la extensión del archivo coincide con alguna de las tres?

Comment: Sii, exactamente

Comment: Si, ¿cual de las 2?

Comment: Si la extension está en una de las tres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que las comparaciones están al revés, `a.includes(b)` revisa si `b` está dentro de `a`

```js
let tipoArchivo = 'text/plain'

console.log('tipo.includes')
for (tipo of ['sql', 'text', 'doc']) {
  // ninguno lo cumple
  console.log(tipo.includes(tipoArchivo))
}

console.log('tipoArchivo.includes')
for (tipo of ['sql', 'text', 'doc']) {
  // alguno lo cumple: 'text'
  console.log(tipoArchivo.includes(tipo))
}
```